# PowerBI Dax creating a summary table from many other tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a number of tables 18 or so and i'm trying to create a summary table that brings all this together, however i'm struggling to workout how i create a column that each cell looks at a different table and gets me a total from each table. Example below

[image]

If anyone can help on how to do this in powerbi that would be awsome

Comment: have you tried to use Power Query to combine the tables?

Comment: @RADO I haven't as i don't really want a single massive table can you explain it would give me the summary table i'm looking for as I think i would still have the same issue

Comment: What is wrong with a single massive table? It's much more efficient and faster than 18 separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerBI go to modelling tab -> Select new table and create a new table Like below:

[image]